# Obtain all value while Gurobi has only one feasible solutions in Python

Tags: python, gurobi

How do I get all the value of the variable while Gurobi has only one feasible solution?
for example:
Optimal objective is 5
and there are four values that can reach the feasible solution,as shown below.
[1, 2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2, 0], [3, 0, 2, 0]
But the Gurobi only show one value,as show below:

```
x[0]：3.0
x[1]：0.0
x[2]：2.0
x[3]：0.0
```

please tell me how do I get all the value.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to enumerate all optimal solutions for a MIP, you can do it with the help of the `PoolGap`, `PoolSolutions` and `PoolSearchMode` parameters.

- The `PoolSolutions` parameter determines how many feasible solutions are stored while solving the MIP.
- The `PoolGap` parameter determines the allowed gap for all stored solutions. Set it to 0.0 to only allow optimal solutions inside the solution pool.
- The `PoolSearchMode` parameter sets the search mode for the MIP tree search. Set it to `2` to search for the `n` best solutions, where `n` is just the value set for `PoolSolutions`.

Here's a minimal example:

```py
import gurobipy as gp

coins = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]

m = gp.Model()
x = m.addVars(8, vtype='I', name="x")
m.addConstr(sum(coins[i]*x[i] for i in range(8)) == 200)

# Parameters
m.Params.PoolSearchMode = 2
m.Params.PoolSolutions = 10**8
m.Params.PoolGap = 0.0

# Optimize
m.optimize()

# Iterate over all found solutions
for k in range(m.SolCount):
    m.Params.SolutionNumber = k
    print([var.Xn for var in m.getVars()])
```

Comment: Do you know how to set the solution of gurobi to be a multiple of 10 instead of all integers? For example, the solution for gurobi has two solutions, as follows: [10,20,50,70] [55,79,30,80] I only want to output solutions that contain only multiples of 10. please tell me how do I get the solution.Thank you very much!

Comment: You can filter the found solutions by `if all(var.Xn % 10 == 0 for var in m.getVars()):` before printing them. Alternatively, you could add an additional constraint that enforces `x[i] == 10*k[i]` where `k[i]` is an integer variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to add additional constraints? For example, my current variables look like this:`x = modelname.addVars(path_number, lb=data_low, ub=data_up, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name='x')`

Comment: @Zying Since you already asked a separated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174352/how-can-i-set-the-solution-of-gurobi-to-be-a-multiple-of-10-instead-of-all-integ), I'd recommend that you provide a minimal example there.

Comment: The minimal example has been uploaded to another issue.If you have a solution, please tell me.Thank you very much!